# Stopping flexbox from collapsing child width when auto margins are set

Tags: css, flexbox

I'm using flexbox to create a sticky footer.

```css
body {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    min-height: 100vh;
    margin: 0;
}

header, footer {
    background-color: #c9c9c9;
    padding: 20px;
}

main {
    flex: 1;
    margin: 0 auto;
    max-width: 300px;
    border: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<header></header>
<main>This is some content</main>
<footer></footer>
```

[JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dejwxzyz/)

This works okay, but the width of `<main>` now collapses to fit the content, rather than expand to the max-width. This only happens when auto margins are set.

Is there any way to make `<main>` expand to the max-width when auto-margins are set?

Comment: So what's the point of `max-width` in this case? Why don't you use `width` instead? It looks it's what you're after for.

Comment: @HashemQolami Because I want `<main>` to decrease in width when the viewport width gets less than 300px.

Comment: Neither would respect the width of the viewport as you've used  absolute lengths in `px` unit.

Comment: @HashemQolami I want it to work like this http://jsfiddle.net/x4vv0wky/. Notice how the width of main decreases when you decrease the width of the container to < 300px (by decreasing the viewport width to < 300px).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Adding `width: 100%;` to `<main>` seems to fix this.

[Fiddle link.](http://jsfiddle.net/dejwxzyz/3/)

```css
*, *:before, *:after {
    box-sizing: border-box;  
}

body {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    min-height: 100vh;
    margin: 0;
}

header, footer {
    background-color: #c9c9c9;
    padding: 20px;
}

main {
    flex: 1;
    margin: 0 auto;
    max-width: 300px;
    width: 100%;
    border: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<header></header>
<main>This is some content</main>
<footer></footer>
```

Comment: It'll definitely solve the problem, much easier than [my approach](http://jsfiddle.net/hashem/dejwxzyz/4/). The point is because of `flex-direction: column` the flex item (`<main>`) won't take the width of its containing block, therefore it would shrink to its contents.